# what does docker export dir mean

Tags: docker

i am following this [tutorial to run mssql in a docker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850957/how-do-i-install-mssql-server-and-or-tools-for-linux-on-16-04).First the user pulls the image

> docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-linux

second he does below

> export DIR=/var/lib/mssql
>   sudo mkdir $DIR

finally he runs

> docker run \
>       -d \
>       --name mssql \
>       -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' \
>       -e 'SA_PASSWORD=' \
>       -p 1433:1433 \
>       -v $DIR:/var/opt/mssql \
>       microsoft/mssql-server-linux

Author explains second step as below

> Create a directory on the host that will store data from the container and keep the value in an environment variable for convenience:

**ask:**
what does the author meant by that and what happens if we dont create the directory

I tried searching for different terms like below

- docker container default path
- docker file system

but not able to understand.Can some one shed some light on this

Comment: `DIR` is just a shell variable, you could as well spell out the directory name each time. It is easy to try what happens when the directory does not exist ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is thing. Consider below code

```
export DIR=/var/lib/mssql
sudo mkdir $DIR
```

I can rewrite it as

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mssql
```

But I will also have to change my RUN command to

```
docker run \
-d \
--name mssql \
-e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' \
-e 'SA_PASSWORD=' \
-p 1433:1433 \
-v /var/lib/mysql:/var/opt/mssql \
microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

Now if you change the directory, then you you will have to update two places. Thats why DIR was used.

If you remove below from your docker run

```
-v /var/lib/mysql:/var/opt/mssql \
```

The data of your DB will be stored inside container at `/var/opt/mssql` and the data will only exist till the container is running. Next time you restart the container the DB will be blank.

That is why you map it to an outside directory on host. So when you restart the container or launch a new one then that directory content would be made available inside the container and the DB will have all the changes you made

Comment: Glad to be of help. If you feel that is the answer you were looking for, please accept the post as an answer